# How to add tapGesture to view and it's subview which is a collectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

So I have a view for which I have a tapGestureRecogniser. Now I am adding a collection inside the view and relying upon it's didSelectItemAt delegate function to detect any touch inside the collectionView cells. But when I click a cell, only my tapGestureRecogniser function is evoked. Please help how to implement this ?

I have tried setting tapGestureRecogniser.cancelsTouchesInView = false, but this leads to both the tapGesture and didSelect being called when clicked on the collectionview cell.

Comment: What you describe is what I would expect. Normally if you attach a tap gesture recognizer to a view, it "swallows" the gesture. So the tap gesture recognizer fires but the cell selection does not. When you set `cancelsTouchesInView = false`, both the tap gesture **and** the `didSelectItemAt()` method get called. What is it you want to happen instead?

Comment: @DuncanC what i want is when user taps on the collectionview only didSelect to happen and when user clicks outside then tapgesture should happen.

Comment: Your description is still unclear. You said "...when user taps on collectionview".  You mean when the uesr taps on a collection view **cell** you want didSelect to be called? And then what about the second part "...when user clicks outside then tap gesture should happen". When the user clicks outside of what? You need to edit your question to show your storyboard and/or the code that sets up your UX, tell us how you are attaching your gesture recognizers, etc.